# Hard disk temprature and spining rate increases gradually

Tags: arch-linux, hard-disk

I have recently installed Arch Linux on my device [Acer Nitro 5 AN515-55](https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B088FLY29Z/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o05_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) after following the installation guide present on the Arch website.

I've noticed that my hard disk temperature and spin rate increase gradually after some time I start my laptop and start using it. My hard disk temperature reaches around 45-49 after this temperature the heat on the surface of the laptop where the hard disk is present also increases (Every time when my laptop hits this temperature I shut down so I don't know if it can go beyond this or not ). The spinning of the hard disk also increases and is related to temperature increase when the temperature hits around 37-39 I start to feel the vibration on the surface of the laptop where the hard disk is present and after some time it starts to make small noise which I think is when the hard disk reaches max speed it happens due to that.

For measuring temperature I use

```
 sudo hddtemp /dev/sda6
```

and for measuring speed I don't know any commands but I have checked which processes are writing to the disk when the spin rate is high and found none of the processes are doing disk read and write.

So far, I have used **powertop** and **hdpram -S** to 1 for reducing the sleep time of the disk and **hdpram -B** to 254 and 128 for reducing the performance of the harddisk but nothing helped.

Please help me out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think that's a fan you're hearing - spinning rust spins at a constant speed, it's not variable (at least, I've never heard of a variable speed HDD)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed the problem.
The problem was not with HDD it was because of GPU. In my fresh Linux there was no GPU driver because of which the GPUs were not regulated.
So, to fix this I installed Nvidia drivers to fix the issue.

Harddrive temperature was getting high because of the GPU which was nearby and it was GPU's whose temperature was rising too and that was affecting other components.

Answer (score 1):

The speed at which the platter in your hard drive spins has (probably) nothing to do with its temperature.

If anything, it has something to do with how often you read or write from the disk – which correlates with your workload, which in turn correlates with the temperature. But the temperature is not the cause for the speed of your hard drive.

If there's something inside your laptop that spins faster, vibrates more and gets louder with temperature, it's a *fan*, not your hard drive. It's *good* your fan gets faster, or else your laptop would get even hotter.
So, none of the `hdparm` is useful here.

If you want to limit the speed of your fan, you need to limit the power usage of your system (because every single watt used by your laptop gets converted to heat). That in turn means you need to limit the biggest user of power in your system – most likely, your CPU. Your CPU has facilities for that – thermal sensors that your OS can use to control the clock speed: if the CPU gets hot, it's already being downclocked.

Not wanting to open a complete different topic here: Look for "thermal throttling" and "CPU speed control"! (if there's new questions about that, please don't add them here, but ask a new question in a new question post.)

Comment: @0xPrateek you're welcome, but there's no need to thank me in words! Use the built-in "upvote" functionality to reward helpful answers.

Comment: Thanks for answering. As you said "If there's something inside your laptop that spins faster, vibrates more, and gets louder with temperature, it's a fan, not your hard drive" but I hear the sound where the hard disk is present and there is no sound near fan area.  The laptop variant I am having contains 1 TB HDD and 256GB SDD (Sorry for the incorrect link I have updated now).

Comment: Again, it's certainly not your hard drive that spins faster because of temperature. There's simply no reason it would. As Bravo says, nearly all hard drives are fixed-speed, and also, hard drives are *very* smooth these days. You're not observing your HDD; you're observing your fan, in all likelihood. Everthing fits: the noise, the temperature, the ineffectiveness of what you're doing.

Comment: My CPU temperature is normally around 35 -40 so I think the CPU won't be causing this heat. I have monitored temperature using sensors but I found nothing.

Comment: I give up. It's a fan. Believe what you will... but your hard drive is both relatively indifferent to temperature and not your main sink of energy/source of heat.

Comment: Yes, I agree that the spinning rate is higher because of temperature I am saying it's somewhat related to each other as the spin rate increases temperature increases. I think why its HDD having problem because the place where I can feel spin and temperature is where my Hard disk is present and I have verified that using the linux command as well. Also I think my harddisk spin is high and that's what make the noise because I observed when spin rate is high and I put my palm over the HDD place the sound reduces and when I move my hands away it start making noises.

Comment: Ok I'll monitor my fan speed and update the results here. As I have not checked if the fan speed is increasing or not using Linux shell so I cannot say better I will confirm and update.